# Unable to open .class files with JGrasp

Tags: jgrasp

I can't open them without receiving an error message.
This is in JGrasp
.class files for Java

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

jGRASP doesn't have a class file viewer or decompiler. You can open one in binary mode, but viewing raw class file contents probably won't be of any use to you.

What exactly are you after, decompilation or a structural view of the class file?